# Intermittent workflow issue - Unable to properly communicate with workflow service

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

We recently patched a SP 2013 Farm and we are having intermittent issues with 2013 workflows

When we try to start 2013 workflows, sometimes it works and sometimes it throws the below error

```
Unable to properly communicate with workflow service
```

I checked the services and the services are up and running (Service bus gateway, Service bus message broker), but we are getting this error message every now and then, say 1 out of 5 times

Please advise on what could be the issue

Comment: Please check whether firewall is turn on. And any errors in the ULS logs?

Answer (score 3):

The intermittent workflow issue doesn't mainly mean it's related to the current Workflow Manager configuration. Most likely it is an instant problem related to the connectivity between the servers over the network.

So that you need to investigate this issue from your side with your Monitor and Network team to do the following:

- Monitor The Server's availability, Network connectivity, and Port Status.
- Monitor the **[Workflow Manager Ports](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-get-service-bus-ports/)** and make sure that the **[Workflow Manager Port Range is blocked.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-port-is-blocked/)**
- From your side,

  - Perform a **[Workflow Manager Health Checklist](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-health-checklist-in-sharepoint/)** to make sure that the Service Bus gateway and Service bus message broker are running properly.
  - Review the Workflow Manager Configuration as mentioned at **[Configure Workflow Manager SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/configure-workflow-manager-sharepoint-2016/)** and **[Configure Workflow Manager SharePoint 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/)**